# How to import part of spreadsheet from xlsm into Access DB

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Recently I started to use Access since I can use Excel functions to manipulate data in Access which quite useful. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have needed functions.

So now I am trying to move all scripts, etc to work with Access DB.

I want to make button which will allow me to load data from let's say **Sheet_Name, Cells A:D** into Access table (**acc_table**), which already exists. Before insert data, table should be cleaned out and replaced with new data from **A:D** table AND **first 5 lines to be ignored**.

I know how to import CSV file but it inserts whole table and I don't know how to specify Sheet name of .xlsm file and how to mention to ignore some lines.

This is how I import whole CSV file into Access DB:

```
Sub doit()

    ' Create an instance of the Access application object.
    Dim objAccess As Access.Application
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

Dim curworkday As String
curworkday = Range("A3").Value
MsgBox curworkday
Dim CSVfile As String
CSVfile = "C:\1.csv"
MsgBox CSVfile
    ' Check that this is the path on YOUR PC for
    Const conPATH = "C:\1.accdb"
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase conPATH
    objAccess.Visible = True

     ' do the Transfer
    objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", _
    "acc_table", CSVfile, True

    ' close out the mdb
    objAccess.Quit
    Set objAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: From Access database use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method.

Comment: When I tryied to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet I am getting error "Microsoft Access does not support this operation for this IISAM type. To perform this action , you must use the 2007 Microsoft Office system or earlier"

Comment: Posting the CSV import code is not useful. Is that code in Excel? You want code in Excel to move data to Access? Edit question to show attempt to import Excel. Use TransferSpreadsheet or Excel automation. Review http://accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm